# How do I extract specific numbers from a list

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping

I started a side project on a game and currently have the following code:

```python
import urllib.request
import re

# Thats the link I would like to extract the numbers from
htmllink =  urllib.request.urlopen("http://currency.poe.trade/search?league=Hardcore+Harbinger&online=x&want=1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-10-11-12-13-14-15-16-23&have=3")

htmltext = htmllink.read().decode('utf-8')
regex = '<small>(.+?)<div class="currencyimg cur20-3"></div>(.+?)<div class="currencyimg cur20-4"></div></small>'
#regex = '<div class="displayoffer-middle">(.+?)</div>'
pattern = re.compile(regex)

price = re.findall(pattern,htmltext)
print(price[0])
```

When trying the currency converter I get the following:

```
('1 &#10799; ', ' &rarr; 0.1429 &#10799; ')
```

I only need the `1` and the `0.1429` out of the output and I want to work with them for calculations but I can't extract them out of the list. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify regex to find exact values. Here is an ugly varian:

```
regex = '<small>(.+?) &#10799; <div class="currencyimg cur20-3"></div> &rarr; (.+?) &#10799; <div class="currencyimg cur20-4"></div></small>'
```

Do not forget to convert them to int, float or Decimal to use in calculations.